# Python dictionary inside function not getting updated with new values

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to replace an inputed dictionary with new values. I don't understand why the value of the dictionary doesn't change outside of the function. It's weird because I remember this working earlier...

`

```
def multiply_by_term(poly, term):

    new_values = []
    for key in poly:
        new_values.append(poly[key] * term[1])
    
    new_key_assign = list(poly.keys())
    for i in range(len(new_key_assign)):
        new_key_assign[i] += term[0]
  
    poly = dict(zip(new_key_assign, new_values))
```

`

I tried changing the value of poly with the dict() and zip() functions, but when I check the value of poly after the function is called, poly doesn't change.

Comment: The line `poly = dict(zip(new_key_assign, new_values))` creates a new local dictionary which is garbage collected when the function returns. You need to mutate the passed dictionary, not create a new one. Or --just  return this new dictionary (better than working by side effect).

Comment: How would I go about changing the passed dictionary? I thought that poly would be the dictionary inputted into the function. Not sure how I would make the inputted dictionary equal to dict(zip(new_key_assign, new_values))

Comment: I would just return that last dictionary and then in the calling code have a line like `poly = multiply_by_term(poly,term)`

Answer (score 1):

By writing `poly = dict(zip(new_key_assign, new_values))`, you will make it a different object from what it was when entering the function. So to keep the same `id` of your dict you just need to clear it before amending it:

```
def multiply_by_term(poly: dict, term: list):
    new_values = [poly[key] * term[1] for key in poly]
    new_key_assign = list(poly.keys())
    for i in range(len(new_key_assign)):
        new_key_assign[i] += term[0]

    poly.clear()
    for i, key in enumerate(new_key_assign):
        poly[key] = new_values[i]

poly = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
multiply_by_term(poly, [10, 20])
```